# How to include OPENJSON in View?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, lateral-join

My JSON object is stored in the table (single cell). Right now, I'm reading the cell and saving the value to @json NVARCHAR(MAX)

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON ( @json )  
WITH (...)
```

, but that obviously doesn't work in views.
How can I do something like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON ( select top 1 json_object from json_raw )  
WITH (...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cross apply` to apply `openjson()` to each and every row of your table:

```
create view jsonview as
select x.*
from json_raw j
cross apply openjson(j.json_object) with (...) as x
```